# fixing boost shared library missing in linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-libraries

I am building a unix c++ program that calls boost, but when i try to run it i get

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

I didn't use to get this error before ( even though i was already calling boost ) , though i don't know what triggered the change. Anyway - doing ldd on the binary, it indeed shows that the library is missing.

I guess the solution would be to add in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH a link to the library containing the .so file - but i can't find it. Where should it be? Is this the right solution?
Note that i don't have sudo privelages on my computer, so i can only change user settings - And also that i'm a linux newb so please try to explain simply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have linked to a very specific version of Boost (1.42.0 in this case). This worked as long as Boost existed in that exact version on your system, but as soon as an update to a more recent version of Boost happened, the linked library could no longer be found.

You might want to adjust your Makefile to link to a more generic version of `libboost_filesystem.so`.